# Sampling without replacement from an unknown set

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, statistics, pseudocode

I have to extract uniformly DFAs (deterministic finite automata) from a set of DFA that I call **S**. It seems a simple problem, but I haven't the set **S**. **S** contains all the DFA of dimension **n** , thus I know dimension of **S**, I can build **S** but I can't because is very large. I know also the dimension of sets **Sm** where for example **S3**  is a subset of **S** and S3 contains all the DFA with 3 states, **Sm** contains all the DFA with m states where m < n .

I have not the set **S** and thus I have to simulate a uniformly sampling. Furthermore I have to do sampling without replacement.   I create a set D={1,2,3........n} and for each value, that I call **i**, in **D** I associate the value ***|Si|/|S|*** where | | indicates the number of elements in the set that is the argument. Namely I created a distribution. Now I can extract a value from D according to this distribution. In this way I found the set from which extract a single DFA. For example if from D I extract 4 then I have to extract uniformly a DFA from **S4**.

But my question is, how can I sample a DFA from **Si** (**S4** in the example above) without replacement? Namely if I have already extracted previously a specific DFA, in the next sampling I must avoid that specific DFA.
Remark that a DFA is a matrix, a table (a bidimensional array).
Remark also that extract a specific DFA means uniformly extract for each cell of the above mentioned table a value in {1,.....,k} where k is the number of the elements of the alphabet (you have to extract also for each state if is accepting or rejecting).

(I have to implement in C++11 but this is pretty irrelevant)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your problem correctly, the trivial solution would be to keep every sampled DFA, and upon generating a new random one - check if it has been generated before. I guess your problem is the large amount of memory required to store them all.

If so, you may keep only the hash of each DFA - e.g. a 128-bit MurmurHash3, and compare the hash of newly generated DFAs with the stored hashes.

Comment: This procedure doesn't seem efficient. For each sampled DFA I have to do comparing with all the  hash of DFA's previously extracted. Furthemore I don't know 128-bit MurmurHash3, assicure it no collisions? (namely 2 dfa with the same hash)

Comment: Hash values can be sorted, so searching if a hash already appeared takes only log2(n) comparisons. The chance for collision is extremely low (search 'hash collision probability). You may use 256-bit hash func. But it would probably be an overkill

Comment: Yes,with 80000 value (my case) and 128 bit probability of collision is about 9,4 * 10^-30. Goog idea sorting also. I have to understand as use  MurmurHash3 alone